# Como ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado de forma automática en sql server

Tags: sql-server

tengo un procedimiento el cual tiene que realizar un calculo de aprox 20millones de registro pero este se tiene que ejecutar en el servidor en una hora en la que no se encuentre ocupado la hora establecida es 2:00 AM  ¿como hago que el procedimiento se ejecute automáticamente a esa hora?

Comment: Creo que esto te puede ayudar, esta en ingles
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348863/how-to-run-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-every-hour

Answer (score 2):

Lo que podrias hacer seria hacer un job o trabajo en sql server ahi puedes poner la hora que se ejecute podria ser en la madrugada te dejo un link donde lo explican paso a paso [link sql server](https://analisisyprogramacionoop.blogspot.com/2016/01/trabajos-jobs-sql-server-2014.html)